# Turn off SharePoint Error Messages

Tags: infopath, error, forms-services, validation, error-handling

Is there a way to turn off error messages, that are returned from InfoPath forms either having invalid data, or permissions.

Here is a picture of them.

[image]

I would perfer for the form to just not submit.

Comment: this is standard infopath behavior and you would need custom code to check for errors before InfoPath does.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a coded submission that verifies data/permissions before the actual submit...

although that would require it to be an Administrator Approved form, and added through central administration. Would that be an issue?